# How can I break line after every anchor element?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to break line after every anchor element using CSS and not doing it manually in HTML?

I've already tried some word-breaks, etc., but none of them worked.

Comment: You can display it as a block so every time `a` tag start in new line

Comment: Setting all anchors to block-level would have some consequences that may be prohibitive. It wouldn't just break the line after.

Comment: Can you share some example html with us, and the css of your own attempt(s), along with the end result you're looking for?

Comment: @Rana: because of the universal selector, you've set the `<style>` element to `display: block`.

Comment: @Rana: what's your point? Regardless of how many elements you added to the `<body>` element  (and there are six elements, the ones you added and the `<script>` block as the last-child), the universal selector still selects the `<style>` element which you styled as 'display: block.'

Comment: Yes, that shows on my side too. Because the universal selector (`*`) has selected all elements - *including the `<style>` element* - and set it's `display` to `block` as you specified. Code does exactly what you tell it to do, regardless of your intent. Consider changing your selector - if it's a problem - to something like `body *` or `*:not(style)`.

Comment: @Rana Open up your browsers developer tools (usually F12 in most browsers) and inspect the code in the `snippet-box-result` (or right-click in the result and select inspect). Even though the `<style>` block is in the `head` of the HTML, the style of the `<style>` element is `display: block` which is why it renders in the resulting page.

Comment: Definitely want to be careful when using the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#the_universal_selector), though.

Comment: Thank you guys for patiently solving my query . Thanks a lot @DavidThomas

Comment: Yes @phentnil I will keep that in mind next time , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a link break after every `a` link element instead of continuing inline text after the link, create a rule with the pseudo-element [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) selector. This will create a block-level element after the link to effectively create a line break for content following immediately to be on a new line. Using properties `content: ""` and `display: block` applied to `a::after` pseudo-element selector makes this possible.

```js
/* Prevent navigation away from the example */
document.querySelectorAll("a").forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
a::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Praesent at interdum quam. Nunc accumsan libero bibendum, dignissim sapien eu, posuere ligula. Duis vel nisl vitae risus ornare lobortis. Donec semper aliquet tellus, ac mollis libero
  interdum at. Proin congue tempus accumsan. Pellentesque a mattis ante, vitae molestie erat. Vestibulum mattis sodales ante sed egestas. Praesent porta urna at eros varius, vitae semper diam sollicitudin. Donec laoreet quam elementum, tristique nulla
  ac, iaculis lectus. Aenean id posuere lectus. Duis et accumsan mi. Sed sit amet aliquet ipsum.</p>
<p>Aliquam sed orci tortor. Pellentesque ac nunc suscipit, sagittis libero et, congue magna. Duis vulputate commodo metus, eget <a href="">placerat</a> metus fringilla sit amet. Duis elementum, leo pretium varius posuere, felis dui tempus est, sed dictum
  quam nisl eu tortor. Sed imperdiet sagittis arcu nec malesuada. Aliquam aliquam ante ut justo iaculis, sit amet eleifend purus condimentum. Donec pulvinar viverra tristique. Morbi hendrerit justo accumsan arcu vulputate, ac ornare augue sagittis. Nullam
  fermentum ipsum erat, in luctus eros vulputate a. Vestibulum sit amet pulvinar nunc. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vestibulum id metus in justo volutpat egestas. Integer porttitor nisi non turpis
  gravida, et rhoncus quam dapibus.</p>
<p>Nullam malesuada risus massa, nec placerat est dignissim sed. Quisque posuere tellus id eros sodales sodales. Etiam hendrerit, ante vel posuere scelerisque, lacus neque faucibus tortor, vitae feugiat odio est eget tellus. Curabitur fermentum et felis
  sed pellentesque. Vivamus facilisis, augue non vehicula dictum, mi ipsum congue augue, sed fringilla urna risus non nunc. Donec eleifend, sem <a href="">pellentesque</a> volutpat viverra, sapien mauris venenatis leo, vel rhoncus orci elit non arcu.
  Fusce condimentum tellus eu sollicitudin sollicitudin. Sed sed sapien varius risus vestibulum mattis. In sollicitudin lacus aliquet finibus porttitor. Praesent gravida auctor bibendum. Donec placerat vehicula arcu. Vivamus ac massa ac dui venenatis
  tincidunt et vel ligula. Nulla luctus eget elit a convallis. Sed ac neque id tellus tincidunt pulvinar.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<span>I am span</span> 
<i>I am i</i> 
<b>I am b</b> 
<div>I am div</div> 
<p>I am p</p>
```

Comment: Why apply to `*` though?

Comment: Because OP wanted to start each element in new line that's why I suggested this @AnuragSrivastava .

Comment: @Rana of course!

Comment: Using universal selector in this way definitely yields better results for all elements within the body element. Your original had merit just as well since using just the universal selector isn't an uncommon practice; it's just used to reset certain properties before selecting more specific elements to apply further styles.